# why netty share same thread for read and write per socket?

Tags: multithreading, netty

as titled:
why netty share same thread for read and write per socket?

when netty write, netty will convert to one task and use the same thread for read. why not open another thread dedicated for write so that performance can improved?

```
the old one: read1->write1->read2->write2. //read 1 will wait write 1 time to read 2.

the new one:  thread A  read1->read2  //no wait to go to read2

              thread B  write1->write2
```

so initial three thread pools:

one for accept
one for read
one for write

Comment: In most networking situations, there's some *relationship* between data read and written. I.e. the data to write depends on what has just been read. There's no benefit to using multiple threads if they're repeatedly having to rendezvous to exchange information

Comment: Why would you expect using two threads to improve performance? I would think it would make it worse since you typically won't receive some data and then send some data without a context switch, and context switches has a non-zero cost.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  because I think the write will influence next read time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  I think the write will influence next read time if share thread

Comment: Okay, maybe it will. And maybe that will be hugely beneficial. For example, maybe the TCP code will be in cache on the core because it just ran the read, so the write will be faster. If you're going to imagine possible problems, why not imagine them on both sides?

Comment: @trustin , can you help to take a look? 3ks

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of reasons.

First, the read and write operations don't do any heavy lifting anyway. The read operation just collects data that's already been processed and the write operation just dispatches the data to be written as possible. So there's no much performance gain to be had for the added complexity.

Second, a typical server or client cadence alternates sending and receiving anyway. With a send thread and a receive thread, this cadence requires passing data from one thread to another which tends to be inefficient. You also wind up needing queues to adapt between threads and backpressure to handle the queue filling. If you keep reading while you're writing, where do you put that data? Do you just keep buffering it in memory?

Third, more threads means more resource consumption and more context switches. To handle a typical receive-process-send cycle, you will need at least one extra context switch. And if you're handling lots of connections, that means lots more threads and it makes it easier for one connection to get a larger share of resources.

Lastly, if you're using a protocol like TLS, your send and receive logic will have inter-dependencies. So your threads will just wind up waiting for each other anyway.

Comment: in actual, I must use one application thread pool to support it. so I need two thread context switch : io read thread->my thread pool ;  my thread pool -> io write thread. so I think it is not import for if the io read thread is same with io write thread. WDYT?

Comment: I think you're still wrong. Consider a write followed by a read. With two threads, it's app to write thread to read thread to app. With one thread, it's app to read/write thread back to app. You still need a context switch to go from writing to reading. And you still have your read thread and write thread contending for connection information.

Comment: jiafu is describing a server app whereas David Schwartz is describing a client app. They both make sense to me in their own context. I wonder if there is such a situation where a single thread is too busy writing and unable to read at the same time.

Comment: @KinCheung Even a server typically receives a query from a client and the sends a response. The cadence is to first receive and then transmit because of what you received. Why force an extra context switch in there?

Comment: Here is my scenario. I have data coming in from a device and that is actually a voice sample. I need to munch it and get data out of it from a third party service and for each of the input chunk I need to write the response back as soon as possible. I have written a netty client and server. The server - munches voice and gets relevant text. The client - sends the voice to server. Assume the client can understand only http . Now I am stuck because the client is not reading as soon as it writes the first chunk , instead is waiting for all the chunks to be read from a file.

Comment: I have tried adding an executor group to the inbound response of the client. But my inbound handler is called only after all the chunks are transferred. Why?